# C# AWS CDK Serverless, publish new version Lambda and create new API resource

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-serverless

I'm new to AWS CDK and what I'm trying to accomplish (using C#) is to version my lambda function, and then create a new API resource referencing the version.

For example: The program accepts a version parameter.

```
    internal CdkAppStack(Construct scope, string id, IStackProps props, string bucketName, string functionName, string version) : base(scope, id, props)
    {
        var bucket = new Bucket(this, bucketName, new BucketProps { 
            BucketName = bucketName
        });

        var handler = new Function(this, $"{functionName}Handler", new FunctionProps
        {
            Runtime = Runtime.DOTNET_CORE_3_1,
            Code = Code.FromAsset("Lambdas\\src\\Lambdas\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1"),
            Handler = "Lambdas::Lambdas.Function::FunctionHandler",
            Environment = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["BUCKET"] = bucket.BucketName,
            },
            FunctionName = functionName
        });

        string apiName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(version) ? $"{functionName}-{version}" : functionName;

        bucket.GrantReadWrite(handler);

        var api = new RestApi(this, $"{apiName}-API", new RestApiProps
        {
            RestApiName = $"{apiName}API",
            Description = $"This service the Lambda - {functionName}.",
            RetainDeployments = true
        });

        var getWidgetsIntegration = new LambdaIntegration(handler, new LambdaIntegrationOptions
        {
            RequestTemplates = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["application/json"] = "{ \"statusCode\": \"200\" }"
            }
        });

        string resource = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(version) ? $"execute-{version}" : "execute";

        var helloWorldResource = api.Root.AddResource(resource);
        var method = helloWorldResource.AddMethod("POST", getWidgetsIntegration);

    }
```

Actual result:

It overrides the lambda and api resource.

Expected result:(version parameter is 3). Added new resource (execute-3)

[AWS Console - Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1hpv.png)

Answer (score 0):

For the given code the process probably looks like this:

1. Current provisioned state includes `execute-2`
2. CDK synthesizes a Cloudformation template where `execute-3` exists and `execute-2` does not exist.
3. Cloudformation figures out that in order to reach the desired state (described in the template) it needs to **delete** `execute-2` and **provision** `execute-3`.

If you literally want to reach what you are describing you will have to add resources and **not delete** previously provisioned ones (say write a loop that runs over 1..version and adds all past versions)

Another (less recommendable) option is to use a [deletion policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.RemovalPolicy.html). This way you can hint cloudformation not the delete `execute-2` (the downside here is that `execute-2`'s lifecycle is no longer managed by any stack --> you will have to manage changes to it manually)